# Did Shakespeare really mean meat pies by baked meats?

Tags: meaning, shakespeare

Here's from *Hamlet*, Act 1, Scene 2(The Arden Shakespeare edited by Harold Jenkins).

> Thrift, thrift, Horatio. The funeral bak'd meats
>
> Did coldly furnish forth the marriage tables.

Jenkins interpreted "bak'd meats" as meat pies.
I wonder why it couldn't be, for example, roasted chickens.

Comment: You *roast* a chicken in the oven, you don't *bake* it. Cakes, breads and pies are typically *baked*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That is a modern use. In Shakespeare's day roasting meant cooking at or over an open flame, typically on a spit; anything in an oven was baked.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Longman Dictionary
Bake:To cook something using dry heat, in an oven.
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bake

Comment: @StoneyB I had no idea! I suppose if the bird was stuffed, then it had to be cooked in an oven. Ivanhoescott, read the definition; cakes, breads, and potatoes are *baked*. **bake** (bread and cakes in an oven)
**roast** (meat or vegetables in an oven)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ooops. [Try again](http://www.elizabethan-era.org.uk/old-elizabethan-recipes.htm)

Comment: @StoneyB Mmmm.... baked swan cooked with lard and butter. Yummy.

Comment: @StoneyB So when was the word 'roasting' first applied to oven cooking?

Comment: @WS2 A very interesting question. On a quick Google Books survey, I find it twice in Robinson Crusoe, but not thereafter until the 19th century: Count Rumford in 1802, and then with increasing frequency into the 1840s. The use seems to have evolved out of the use of iron Dutch-ovens and 'roasters' at about the same time as open fires were being displaced by stoves.

Comment: @WS2 There is also an earlier use in metallurgy - ores were roasted in ovens - but I doubt that had much influence.

Comment: @StoneyB I must admit that it had never previously occurred to me that the etymology of *roast* was from *rôtir* - to turn. And this has come full circle now that many modern ovens contain a *rotisserie* device. This is a far cry from my grandmother's oven-in-the-wall (above the open fire), in a Norfolk village in the late 1940s before there was either an electricity or a gas supply to the cottage.

Comment: @StoneyB It is also of interest, and perhaps of significance to this conversation, that whilst *roast* has come to English via Norman French, the etymology of *bake* is via the Saxon route from German.

Comment: Hey MariLou, I think you are confusing historic and modern usage.  Also (today) in English, if you say "bake" a chicken it tends to mean IN A CLOSED POT in an oven; "roast" a chicken tends to mean "in the open in an oven" (perhaps on one of those spiny sticks; or just on a flat open pan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Baked* for Shakespeare would have meant cooked in an oven, and *meat* was not restricted to  flesh but included any food.

Chickens, however, would probably have been roasted: cooked on a spit over an open flame.

Meats (in the modern sense) were usually baked in a pastry shell of some sort, but again this did not have quite the sense of the modern *pie*: often the pastry served only as a container and was not eaten.

Comment: Didn't they usually use an oven to cook meat alone, i.e. without pastry?

Comment: @ivanhoescott The recipes I've seen call for meat to be roasted or seethed, both involving an open fire. Keep in mind that only wealthy households had ovens; ordinary folk cooked at the hearth and bought bread from a baker.

Comment: I have noticed that the funeral had been held almost a month before the wedding.
I think the baked meats were unlikely animal or fish *meat*.

Comment: @ivanhoescott I think it very unlikely that Hamlet intends the statement to be taken literally - he is deliberately exaggerating the brevity of time involved.

Comment: Maybe so, but I'm asking about the literal meaning.

Comment: As I said, the literal meaning of *meat* is "food", not narrowly "flesh"

Comment: I knew. So the above comment of mine was meant to express my agreement with you.

Comment: @ivanhoescott I beg your pardon, I misunderstood you.

Comment: It was my fault that I hadn't made it clear.

Comment: While *meats* covered all foods (and does so still, though that use is now rare) at the time, the sense pertaining only to the flesh of animals was also current and Shakespeare used both (and the sense where it is used of the edible part of a fruit, egg or other item that has an edible and inedible part). The fact that this form of baking with the crust as a container (generally discarded or donated to beggars) was most often used of flesh would suggest that was the sense meant then, but its being a figurative use means the ambiguity is irrelevant as it works equally well either way.

Answer (score 2):

This line should not be translated literally. The "funeral bak'd meats" is referring to Hamlet's very recently deceased father whose barely cold remains "coldly furnish forth" (laid the table for) the opportunity for his uncle to marry his mother. Remember that Hamlet is disgusted by the marriage taking place so soon, so his language is a bit vitriolic.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following source  [bak'd meats](http://books.google.it/books?id=BvdBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=bak%27d%20meat%20in%20shakespeare&source=bl&ots=RZmBdPAl-r&sig=Xl3nO3lc2jNHHw7HOEi8-7-Y_vs&hl=it&sa=X&ei=434PVNqHDKLQ7Ab30oCwBQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=bak'd%20meat%20in%20shakespeare&f=false) means generally meat prepared by baking, but in the common usage of our ancestors it refers more usually  to a meat pie or perhaps any other kind of pie.

> - 'meat dressed by the oven'  Dr. Johnson

Source: A Glossary: Or, Collection of Words, Phrases, Names, in the works of Shakespeare and his Contemporaries. By Robert Nares